# Whine from PC internal speaker

Tags: motherboard, post, system-sounds

I have a Gigabyte GA-990XA-UD3 motherboard with an internal speaker fitted to the front-panel connector block. It starts emitting a whine part-way through the POST, and I wonder if anyone can suggest why and how to stop it

I get the correct beep after the POST is complete, but the whine never stops. I can only imagine that some components on the motherboard have degraded but remain functional

I would just disconnect it, but the diagnostic beeps have been useful on more than one occasion

Comment: When it is whining, after it is running, I'd still manually disconnect the speaker[s] to ensure what you are hearing really is from your speakers.  Another test might be to connect earphones to see if these also whine.  Sourcing sound and the causes is often deceivingly difficult.

Comment: @DaaBoss: I've already determined that by obstructing the hole in the little ceramic speaker enclosure: the noise disappears. I also have a 2in magnetic coil speaker that I intend to try, but I don't hold much hope.

Comment: You need to rule out that it is the speaker itself though.

Comment: @LPChip: I am sure it is not the speaker as the noise cuts in half-way through the POST, a couple of seconds before the "success beep". I have  also tried two different ceramic speakers.

Comment: Don't rule it out just because theory suggest so. I have been proven wrong before by theory when practical told otherwise.